# How to call php script via Json and return array of days to be disable on the Datepicker

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json

In the following example, I need to know how to call, via json, a php script that reads a MySql table, and return the array with the $myBadDates to be disable:

```
$(function() {
        $( "#pickdate" ).datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd MM yy',
            beforeShowDay: checkAvailability
            });

})


var $myBadDates = new Array("10 October 2010","21 October 2010","12 November 2010");

function checkAvailability(mydate){
var $return=true;
var $returnclass ="available";
$checkdate = $.datepicker.formatDate('dd MM yy', mydate);
for(var i = 0; i < $myBadDates.length; i++)
    {    
       if($myBadDates[i] == $checkdate)
          {
        $return = false;
        $returnclass= "unavailable";
        }
    }
return [$return,$returnclass];
}
```

Here is my php script : close_dates.php, how do I send the json ajax request and get the array result into the checkAvailability Function : 
 >

```
include 'panel/db.php';
$dates_closed = array();

 ///  Query Dates Closed ///
 $query = "SELECT dates from closed_dates order by dates ";  
 $result = mysql_query($query);
 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   $days  = $row['dates'];
   array_push($date_closed,$days);
 }   
 echo json_encode($date_closed);
```

?>

Comment: By calling a php script do you mean that you need to send a get request to the file

Comment: you can send a json using ajax , you can't call via json unless you define some function names/code and use eval

Comment: yes, I mean sending a request to php script, who will read a table, and return array of dates, with json_encode($myBadDates); instead of having declare my array : $myBadDates

Comment: Here is my php script : close_dates.php, how do I send the json ajax request and get the array result into the checkAvailability Function : <br> > <?php
//  get dates closed //

 include 'panel/db.php';
 $dates_closed = array();

     ///  Query Dates Closed ///
     $query = "SELECT dates from closed_dates order by dates ";  
  $result = mysql_query($query);
     while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $days  = $row['dates'];
    array_push($date_closed,$days);
  }   
     echo json_encode($date_closed);    
?>     </code